# Add Android Beacon Library to cordova project

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, android-library

I am trying to make a hybrid app which will transmit as beacon, I am using https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon 
plugin but transmission works only for iOS, for android I need to add Android Beacon Library to cordova project. I have never added any android library before. How can I add this library to my cordova project:http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

Comment: The second link refers to Native android and not Cordova Library. But first plugin says it supports both IOS and Android

Comment: advertising device as an iBeacon (iOS only, not yet for Android)